# Passing values from one class to another class in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am sudying OOP on Python, in one excersise I have the following:

```
class Burrito:
    def __init__(self, meat):
        self.meat = self.set_meat(meat)

    def set_meat(self, meat):
        self.meat = ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]
        if meat in self.meat:
          self.meat = meat
        else:
          self.meat = False
        return self.meat

    def get_meat(self):
        return self.meat

    def get_cost(self, cost = 25):

        if self.meat in self.meat:
          return cost
        else:
          return 0


newBurrito = Burrito("steak")
print(newBurrito.get_cost())
```

The goal of this excercise is ti check if the **Burrito(meat)** is a "steak" or not, if so the value is 25.

Now I was given another class called Meat and with this one I have to rewrite the code to do the same thing and I have not to alter the **class Meat** only the Burrito class, this is the code I have:

```
class Meat:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False

class Burrito:
    def __init__(self, meat):
        self.meat = Meat(meat)

    def get_cost(self, cost = 25):
        if self.meat in self.meat:
          return cost
        else:
          return 0


newBurrito = Burrito("steak")
print(newBurrito.get_cost())
```

As you can see in the cost method I don't know how to pass the value from Class Meat to Class Burrito, can you help me please?

Comment: `self.meat in self.meat` ... that's not what you want. Probably this is meant to be `self.meat in ["chicken", ..., "tofu"]`, right?

Comment: Why would you supply a cost to the `get_cost` method? "Here's a value, give it back to me" makes for a pretty meaningless function.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_cost(self, cost = 25):
    if self.meat.get_value() == "steak":
      return cost
    else:
      return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Meat:
    def __init__(self, value=False):
        self.set_value(value)

    def get_value(self):
        return self.value

    def set_value(self, value):
        if value in ["chicken", "pork", "steak", "tofu"]:
            self.value = value
        else:
            self.value = False


class Burrito:
    def __init__(self, meat):
        self.meat = Meat(meat)

    def get_cost(self, cost = 25):
        if self.meat:
            return cost


newBurrito = Burrito("steak")
print(newBurrito.get_cost())
```

I have slightly changed your codes. When you use *Meat(meat)* in ***init*** function, *Meat(meat)* construct an object in which *meat.value* is the result. What you need to do is to simply judge if it is True.